# Dates from lookup fields that are set using a workflow carry over dates that are a day behind the source date. Why is that?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, lookup-column

I have dates pulled from lookup fields from a list and set to new fields on a different list but the dates are one day behind.

I checked to see if they are indeed both just `Date` and not `Date and Time`, and everything else including the regional settings, which are the same.

Why are the dates coming in as one day behind for any date field between these two?

Comment: A similar issue, although remains unsolved: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32642/date-format-bug-in-lists. I'd actually advice to try the "Date and Time" option for both, so that the hours should be at least in theory the same.

Comment: Also in your workflow, have you defined the "Return field as" to "Short date"? The workflow might converse the "Date" to "Date and Time" format without this setting, and set a built-in default timezone hours. See [a picture about the setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR4hu.png).